# arduino cont down timer in minutes with out using delay

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, timers

i have one code with delay pleas help me remove the delay i will using this code in air cooler with some sensors delay stop working sensors

```
void startCycle(int cycleTimeInMinutes, const char *type) {
  lcd.clear();
  const char *topRow[1] = { type };
  printTopRow(topRow, 1, 5);

  cool1(true);

  for (int cycleTimeLeft = cycleTimeInMinutes; cycleTimeLeft > 0; cycleTimeLeft--) {
    char buffer[2];
    const char *bottomRow[3] = { itoa(cycleTimeLeft, buffer, 10), "Minutes"};
    printBottomRow(bottomRow, 3, 6);
    delay(60000);
  }
  cool1(false);
}
```

Comment: Check this sketch: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay